# Help updating record's field with lookup's child record

Tags: apex, batch, lookup, relationships, field-update

I have three objects:

Order__c
Package__c
Account

Package has a relationship with account and order.

Order has a relationship with account.

If a package has an account attached to it, how can I make it also attach to that account’s order?

```
    Set<Id> accountOnPack = new Set<Id>();
    List<Package__c> packs = new List<package__c>();
    for(package__c package : packages){
        if(package.order__c== null && package.received__c =true ){
            accountOnPack.add(package.get(id).Account__c);
            //query to grab order from accounts?
            // order__c orders = OrderQueries.getOrders(item.account__r.id);
            packs.add(package);
        }
    }
```

From here I need to add these packages to the account’s order. Where would I go from here?
How can I then query for the account's orders and attach it to the packages?

Comment: Do you want to relate account record in your order which is related to package?

Comment: There could be multiple orders attached to an account? If yes, then how would you identify which order needs to be attached to which package?

Comment: It would be the most recent order that is in the status" prepared".

Answer (score 0):

I assume your problem statement is: If Package has Account and The Account have Ordered, then you want to relate that package to the order

```
   //fetch all Account Id's from the Package records:
   Map<Id, Id> packageToAccountId = new Map<Id, Id>();
   for(package__c package : packages){
    if(string.isBlank(package.Account__c))
        packageToAccountId.put(package.id, package.Account__c);
   }

   //get all orders related to that Account
   //update the Orders__r relationship name accordingly
   Map<Id, Account> accountToOrderId = Map<Id, Account>(List<Account>([Select id, (Select Id from Orders__r where Account__c in :packageToAccountId.values() and package__c = '' limit 1) from Account where id in :packageToAccountId.values()]));

   //process starts here
   List<Package__c> packageToUpdate = new List<package__c>();
   for(package__c package : packages){
    Account currentAccount = accountToOrderId.get( packageToAccountId.get(package.Id) );
    if(package.order__c == null && package.received__c = true ){
        //assuming one account has only one related order. I used Limit 1 in query
        //update Orders__r relationship name accordingly
        if(currentAccount.Orders__r[0] <> null && currentAccount.Orders__r[0] <> '' )
            packageToUpdate.add(new Package__c(id = package.id, Order__c = currentAccount.Orders__r[0]Id));
    }
   }
```

Please note that the code is not tested but must fulfill your requirement. You have to update the code at some points!!